# Inverting iptables interfaces

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, iptables

I'm building a LAN to WLAN router and I need setting up NAT using `iptables`.

I don't get the description of the -i and -o command line switches (emphasis mine) in the [MAN page](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html#lbAH):

> **[!] -i**, --in-interface name
>       Name of an interface via which a packet was received (only for packets entering the INPUT, FORWARD and PREROUTING chains). **When the "!" argument is used before the interface name**, the sense is inverted. If the interface name ends in a "+", then any interface which begins with this name will match. If this option is omitted, any interface name will match.
>
> **[!] -o**, --out-interface name
>       Name of an interface via which a packet is going to be sent (for packets entering the FORWARD, OUTPUT and POSTROUTING chains). **When the "!" argument is used before the interface name**, the sense is inverted. If the interface name ends in a "+", then any interface which begins with this name will match. If this option is omitted, any interface name will match.

The position of the optional ! seems to be before the hyphen. But from the description I understand it should be before the interface name and not before the switch itself.

Is it

```
iptables !-i eth0
```

or

```
iptables -i !eth0
```

I was not able to find examples using this and I'd like to get it right.

I have tried both and none of them seems to work:

Using `!-i` seems to replace that with the last command starting with `i` that I used (?):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING !-i eth0 -o wlan+ -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ifconfig eth0 -o wlan+ -j MASQUERADE
Bad argument `ifconfig'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ !-i
ifconfig
```

Using `!eth0` gives "event not found":

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i !eth0 -o wlan+ -j MASQUERADE
-bash: !eth0: event not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!` is a special bash character for history expansion and has to be escaped.

The exclamation mark needs to be escaped in single quotes `'` and the position is before the interface name, not before the argument.

So your command becomes

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i '!'eth0 -o wlan+ -j MASQUERADE
```

Note that `POSTROUTING` and `-i` don't work together, so it has to be fixed to

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan+ -j MASQUERADE
```

anyway and you got rid of the whole problem.